# Copying mysql databases from /var/lib/mysql_old won't let mysql-server to start

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

After `mysql-server` on my ubuntu 20.04 server crashed, I copied `/var/lib/mysql` to backup folder on the server. Now I tried to restore all databases by copying from backup path to  `/var/lib/mysql` but after doing this it won't let `mysql-server` to start.

Also I have checked the `journalctl -u mysql` for any log but it just says `Failed to start MySQL Community Server.`

I have also tried to using `mysqldump` to generate `sql` backup **from backup folder** and import it directly to `phpmyadmin` but it won't recognize the databases to generate backup

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **After mysql-server ... crashed**, I copied /var/lib/mysql to backup folder...

If you've had a crash *previously* and are now starting to think about your Recovery Strategy, then Good.
If you've *had* a crash and your attempted *solution* is to try and take a backup of the [crashed] database?  *Not* so Good.

You need to be taking *proper*, Database Backups (using **mysqldump** or a similar tool) on a regular basis.

Mucking about at the file system level is *not* recommended, especially if the database is running.
There are many, many reasons for this but the *important* one is that even if you *do* get a "copy" of the files "under" a running database, you will *almost certainly* **not** be able to *recover* that database using those files.